# Engine Temperature from OBD data

Tags: engine, coolant, obd-ii, temperature

Engine Coolant temperature is obtained from OBD. But there is no PID to get engine temperature. Obviously, they are related, rather proportional I guess. But can there be a case where my engine is extremely hot, while my coolant temperature reading is in the normal range (say around 90 C). If so, how can one catch it from OBD parameters? Which parameters will indicate this (show unusual behavior)?

In general, any calculation/method to calculate the engine temperature from OBD data?

Comment: What do you consider to be "engine temperature"?

Comment: The temperature in the engine cylinders. Actually the engine as a whole. Mechanics refer as - "Your engine is overheating, so it becomes difficult to start your engine after idling at a traffic/jam for sometime"

Comment: IN the engine cylinders? That's tough to tell. The temperature of the engine as a whole is reflected by the coolant temperature, as coolant is flowing through the engine cooling channels.

Answer (score 3):

PID 05 is Engine coolant temperature.

-40 minimum 215 °C maximum.

The formula is A-40.